# Want to Share Internet Connection from PC via a Linksys Router - Connected but no Internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-xp, router, wireless-access-point

I have a cyber cafe but I was robbed of my Wireless router recently. I want to be able to share Internet connection wirelessly from the PC I use as server to wiressless enabled computers. I got a Linksys router (Linksys WRT542G-2) which I connected to a USB ethernet Adapter. I have had it setup before but the same setting I used on the old one that got missing isn't working on the new one I just bought. I was advised to format my Server PC which I did format with Windows XP, but the issue persists and I'm short of ideas right now, hence bringing it forth to the experts on-board to help out.

**This is my cafe setup:**

Internet from Modem --> Switch --> All client computers and PC used as server. No issue with LAN connections.

**Adapter1(LAN)**

- IP address: 192.168.8.200 (Static IP required by the cafe client I use)
- Subnet: 255.255.255.0
- Default gateway and DNS1: 192.168.8.1
- Internet connection shared

**Adapter2 (for Wireless Hotspot)**

- IP address: 192.168.0.1
- Subnet: 255.255.255.0
- Default gateway and DNS are left blanked

**Router Settings**

- Connection Type: Automatic, DHCP
- Router IP changed to: 192.168.0.2
- Subnet: 255.255.255.0
- Security: None
- SSID: Set

With the setup above, systems can connect to the Router but no Internet connection. I disabled firewall and blocked my antivirus but no headway.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What was your server running before you installed XP on it? You should consider upgrading as Windows XP is no longer support by Microsoft and is open it a lot of security issues.

Answer (score 0):

They are on different subnets and your netmask is set to 192.168.0/24 and 192.168.8.0/24 respectively. Also you need to set a default gateway / dns otherwise your packets will have nowhere to go!

I just reread your post...  Try this:
Disable WAN on your wireless router and make sure you're assigning IP's on the same subnet as the working connection.

Comment: 192.168.0.1 was the IP the system gave to the Hotspot adapter when the first adapter (LAN) was shared. Subnet Mask are same (255.255.255.0). The stolen router worked well with this configuration